# Copy Build Configuration from another project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, build

I have a solution with many projects in it.  I have added a new one, but it doesn't seem to share the same build configurations as the others.  I want to copy the build configuration from another project and make it available to the new project.

As you can see in the image below, all my other projects have net462-source, but not the one for which I have lowered the drop down.  It only has Debug and Release.

How do I copy the build configuration over?

[image]

Comment: @user442920were u able to solve this, nobody answered does anyone don't know the answer

Comment: Sorry I can't remember if I solved this and I have left that company and do not use VS anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to find an answer to your copy question but for future projects you can utilize Project Templates and Property Sheets to apply shared configuration across multiple projects.

**Use custom Project Template for new projects:**

1. Create a new empty project.
2. Apply the *net462-source* configuration to the new project.
3. Export a new project template by following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates.
4. When creating a new project select the new project template and it will automatically apply the correct configuration settings.

[Add Custom Project Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6SoT.jpg)

**Use shared Property Sheets for multiple projects:**

1. Create a property sheet in the solution folder by following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/create-reusable-property-configurations#to-create-a-property-sheet.
2. Apply your shared properties settings to the .props file either manually or through the *Property Manager* window and click save.
3. In the *Property Manager* select all the projects that you want to apply the property sheet to and *right click->Add Existing Property Sheet...*

[Add Existing Property Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tko9L.jpg)

**Note:** Property sheets can also contain "Conditions" like .vcxproj files.

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='net462-source|Win32'">
  <ClCompile>
    <WarningLevel>Level4</WarningLevel>
  </ClCompile>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```